# how to find value in multilevel dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following:

```
trd_potfolio = {"TATASTEEL":{"token":"12345"},"VEDL":{"token":"5675"}}
for i in trd_potfolio:
    print(i["token"])
```

I want to find the values of token, how can I find that

Comment: The `token` key might be nested in any level of the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
trd_potfolio = {"TATASTEEL":{"token":"12345"},"VEDL":{"token":"5675"}}
for x in trd_potfolio:
    print(trd_potfolio[x]['token'])
```

using `dict.values()`

```
for v in trd_potfolio.values():
    print(v['token'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use for loop and then pull the values using `.values()`

```
trd_potfolio = {"TATASTEEL":{"token":"12345"},"VEDL":{"token":"5675"}}
for i in trd_potfolio.values():
    print(i["token"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option, if you want to be able to choose a differnt `key` to use a funciton to do so like the following:

```
def findkeys(node, kv):
    if isinstance(node, list):
        for i in node:
            for x in findkeys(i, kv):
               yield x
    elif isinstance(node, dict):
        if kv in node:
            yield node[kv]
        for j in node.values():
            for x in findkeys(j, kv):
                yield x

trd_potfolio = {"TATASTEEL":{"token":"12345"},"VEDL":{"token":"5675"}}

print(list(findkeys(trd_potfolio, 'token')))
# ['12345', '5675']
trd_potfolio = {"TATASTEEL":{"token":"12345","test":{"token":"12345"} },"VEDL":{"token":"5675"}}
print(list(findkeys(trd_potfolio, 'token')))
# ['12345', '12345', '5675']
```

This will work to even more nested `dict` and applicable to `list`

Answer (score 0):

The simple loop through a dictionary loops through its keys. You want to loop through its values.

So,

```py
trd_potfolio = {"TATASTEEL":{"token":"12345"},"VEDL":{"token":"5675"}}
for i in trd_potfolio.values(): # loop through values
    print(i["token"])
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pleasure to use py3.8:

```
d = {"TATASTEEL":{"token":"12345"},"VEDL":{"token":"5675"}}
for k, v in d.items():
    if (t := 'token') in v:
        print(f'{k = }, v[{t!r}] = {v[t]}')

# k = 'TATASTEEL', v['token'] = 12345
# k = 'VEDL', v['token'] = 5675
```